# open an unsupported file type with a program automatically in a batch file

Tags: batch-file, exe

I am trying to open a file using a program. I would like to automatically do this with a batch file. Everything I need to run is in the same folder. I am not that good at batch files or coding but I am trying to get better, if anyone knows how to do this that would be great.

I have tried

```
.\location\application .\location\file
exit
```

and

```
START /B /I ".\location\application" ".\location\file"
exit
```

i have tried switching the order of the app and file but it does not work, most of the time it does nothing, but sometimes it opens the app but does not open the file.

Comment: Have you tried anything? If you have, then mention it on your question and tell on which step did you fail. A lot of us want to help you but please read [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Anyway, welcome to StackOverflow :)

Comment: `my.exe pathTo\file.filetype` ? Depends on your executable I would say.

Comment: As @geisterfurz007 said, it depends on the application you're talking about. Some application may need some special arguments or preparations. What is the program you are talking about? Use the documentation (helpdesk, googling, manual, ...). And also be a little bit more specific, saying "it does not work" is vague. What happened during your attempts?  Nothing, error, computer crashed, ... be more specific. It may help us understand the problem

Comment: Your second approach will fail because start.exe takes the first argument in parentheses as the window title. Insert a dummy pair. `Start.exe "" /B /I ...` See [Start /? or ss64.com](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html)

Comment: thanks, that was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The approach:

```
START /B /I ".\location\application" ".\location\file"
```

will fail because Start takes the first argument in <s>parentheses</s> double quotes as the window title. Insert a dummy pair of double quotes to circumvent this.

```
START "" /B /I ".\location\application" ".\location\file"
```

The help `start /?` doesn't explicitly state this.
[ss64.com](http://ss64.com/nt/start.html) only says:

> Always include a TITLE this can be a simple string like "My Script" or
>   just a pair of empty quotes "" According to the Microsoft
>   documentation, the title is optional, but depending on the other
>   options chosen you can have problems if it is omitted.